# Get a IEnumerable<T> from a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

public class Item
    {
        ...
    }

```
public class Order
{
    public List<Item> Items
    ...
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<Order> Orders
    ...
}
```

Now, using LINQ I need to get all items that a customer bought. How can I?

I tried something like `var items = from o in cust.Orders select o.Items;` but result is `IEnuberable<List<Item>>` and I wanna just one `IEnumerable<Item>`.

I'm asking here to try to avoid coding 2 loops.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), which is represented in query expressions as second (and subsequent) `from` clauses:

```
var items = from order in customer.Orders
            from item in order.Items
            select item;
```

Alternatively, to ignore query expressions:

```
var items = customer.Orders.SelectMany(order => order.Items);
```